# Best way to test for total reachability

Tags: language-agnostic, graph-theory, projection, reachability

I have a set of nodes, each of which is connected to at least one other node. I would like to know if the connections are such that each node is reachable from every other. For example:

```
1--2
   |
3--4
```

Versus:

```
1--2

3--4
```

I am convinced this kind of reachability testing can be projected in terms of an [exact cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), however I can't seem to get my brain wrapped around how to do so. Does anyone have any pointers, documentation, web sites, etc., on how to do this? Examples would be extremely valuable.

**Update:** My ignorance has betrayed me, as it would seem there are far more efficient algorithms for this kind of test. If you have one, please point me to it.

Comment: I don't understand. Checking that a graph is connected is polynomial. Why do you want to reduce it to the NP-complete exact cover problem?

Comment: @Pascal - it is even linear in E

Comment: @Andreas no, they are undirected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- start from any node and do a depth/breadth first traversal
- count number of visited node (of course, dont visit any node twice!)
- compare counted number with total number

Comment: +1 But I think this algorithm requires the graph to be undirected?

Comment: Should be straight forward to transform a directed in an undirected graph, if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a fast (but quite complicated) algorithm for maintaining connectivity dynamically (i.e. under edge insertions/deletions), shown in this paper: [Poly-logarithmic deterministic fully-dynamic algorithms for connectivity, minimum spanning tree, 2-edge, and biconnectivity](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=502095&dl=GUIDE&coll=GUIDE&CFID=70802902&CFTOKEN=45890547)

The basic idea is maintaining a spanning tree. The easy cases are inserting an edge, and deleting a non spanning tree edge. The problem is when deleting a spanning tree edge, because now there is not guaranteed connectivity - we have to search efficiently an alternate route to connect the broken parts, otherwise the graph is disconnected.